# Fundamental theorem of Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E/F$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, let F$(H)$ be the fixed field of $H$,and if $K$ is an intermediate field,let G$(K)$ be $Gal(E/K)$, the fixing group of $K$.

Suppose F$(H)=K$. If $H \unlhd G$, then $K/F$ is normal

Proof: Aim: If F$(Gal(K/F))=F$ then $K/F$ is Galois

Note that $F \leq$ F$(Gal(K/F))$ is always true. Then $Gal(K/F) \leq $ G$(F)$

Since $H \unlhd G$, we have $\sigma H \sigma =H$ for all $\sigma \in G \implies$ F$(\sigma H \sigma)=$ F$(H)=K=\sigma(K)$. Then I stuck here. I think it somehow has to do with the equation $\sigma(K)=K$ to prove $G(F) \leq Gal(K/F)$.

Can anyone guide me?

EDIT: Since $\sigma (K)=K$, $\sigma$ is an $F$-automorphism of $E \implies G(F) \leq Gal(K/F)$. Is this correct?